# How to extract public key from attestation certificate to use it for signature verification?

Tags: public-key, openssl

I want to extract the public key from a certificate to verify a given signature (to answer my own [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/30809/how-to-verify-a-signature-with-openssl-methods-from-the-ecdsa-class) in relation to the registration part).

I've tried `openssl x509 -in certificate.pem -pubkey -noout | openssl enc -base64 -d > publickey.pub` and read it with `hexdump -C publickey.pub`
I've got a hexdecimal string, which is 182 characters long. I've expected 128, because I need two coordinates in it, which are 64 characters long.

I think that I only have got the public key, but headers or anything else too. So would you like to help me how I can extract the public key in a hexadecimal string?

Answer (score 1):

The [`openssl x509` manual page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/x509.html) describes the `-pubkey` option as:

> -pubkey
>          
>   outputs the the certificate's SubjectPublicKeyInfo block in PEM format.

[The PEM format consists of a Base64-encoded DER file](https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file), with header and footer lines added.  Once you strip the header and footer and Base64-decode the data (which your `openssl enc` command should indeed do), you're left with a DER file, which contains [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) data in a binary encoding.

Where you're going wrong is in trying to read the DER output directly with a hex editor.  Instead, you need decode it using an ASN.1 parser, such as [`openssl asn1parse`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/asn1parse.html).

Alternatively, you might prefer to simply use:

```
openssl x509 -in certificate.pem -text -noout
```

and extract the public key coordinates (which will probably be shown as sequences of bytes in hexadecimal) from the (more or less) human-readable `-text` output.

Comment: `openssl asn1parse` defaults to "PEM" input -- really base64 here, since unlike most other openssl PEM functions `asn1parse` ignores the type in the BEGIN line -- so either skip the `enc -base64 -d` or use `asn1parse -inform der`. And `asn1parse` on any SPKI only gives you a `BIT STRING` for the actual key unless you add `-dump` in which case you must know/decode the 1-octet for unused bits as well as for EC the (not always trivial) SEC1/X9.62 encoding. So `x509 -noout -text`, or `pkey -pubin -noout -text` on the SPKI, is preferable.